# OutOfRange Index while parsing Tweets in JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing, twitter

I have made a simple application, which uses the Twitter Search API and looks for tweets based on topic name and stores the texts in a text file. I am getting 100 tweets per page but sometimes I am getting 'OutOfRange' index error and the execution stops right there.

```
topic = raw_input('Enter the topic name: ')

f = open('out.txt', 'w')

for y in range(1, 15):
    j = urllib2.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+topic+'&rpp=100&page='+str(y))
    print('Done with page #'+str(y))
    j_obj = json.load(j)
    for x in range(1, 100):
        current = j_obj['results'][x]['text']
        f.write(str(''.join(c for c in current if ord(c) < 128))+'\n')
f.close()
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem and finish the program execution?

I am getting error:

```
current = j_obj['results'][x]['text']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why do `for x in range(1,100)` and not `for x in j_obj['results']: print x['text']` for example? (Mind you, you can also get the number of results by using `len(j_obj['results'])`. This will keep you safe from twitter returning i.e. 99 or 90 results instead of 100.

Comment: Maybe there are not 100 or 200 results but also 231. in this case it will fail when you reach result number 214